# How many non congruent trapeziums are possible with the side lengths from {1,3,4,5,6}

Tags: permutations, combinations

I need to find number of mutually non  congruent trapeziums with side lengths from {1,3,4,5,6}.

I know for a trapezium with a,c as non parallel sides the condition for my question is that

$$|a-c|<b+d<a+c$$

But i cant apply it to count the cases. Can someone help in how to get the number of cases?

Comment: Have you tried drawing them? While having different side lengths *usually* doesn't imply non-congruence, here it does, because no multiples are possible within the set.

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof i would like a better solution than drawing them out

Comment: Do the side lengths have to be different?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter yes

Answer (score 3):

If $a$ and $c$ are the nonparallel sides then the correct (necessary and sufficient) conditions for the existence of a nondegenerate trapezium are
$$|a-c|<|b-d|<a+c\ .\tag{1}$$
There is no condition on $b+d$.

From $\{1,3,4,5,6\}$ you can choose $b>d$ in ${5\choose2}=10$ ways, and from the remaining lengths you can choose $a>c$ in ${3\choose2}=3$ ways. Therefore you obtain $30$ quadruples $(a,b,c,d)$, which you have to test for $(1)$. All admissible quadruples give rise to two mirror symmetric trapezoids.

Comment: Should we consider the mirror symmetric trapezoids?@Christian Blatter

Comment: @sani: It is up to you to decide whether you want to count two mirror-inverted trapezoids as one or as two types.